Comparing numbers of solutions to $\sin(\sin x)=\cos(\cos x)$, $\sin(\sin x)=\tan(\tan x)$, and $\cos(\cos x)=\tan(\tan x)$ in $(0,\pi/2)$

Let set $A$ contain solutions of $\sin(\sin x) = \cos(\cos x)$.
Let set $B$ contain solutions of $\sin(\sin x) = \tan(\tan x)$.
Let set $C$ contain solutions of $\cos(\cos x)= \tan(\tan x)$.
Where $x$ lies in $(0, \pi/2)$ for all of them.
We have to compare the number of elements in each.

I understand we can try graphically but then analysis using calculus would be required I guess.
Please help me with the approach of this problem.
Attempt:
I have tried to graph each function and check. But for $\cos(\cos x)$ I'd be facing an issue as it has an inflection point.
Using graphing tool I see $\cos(\cos x)> \sin(\sin x)$ in the given interval. This I should be able to prove analytically also.
In $\tan(\tan x)$, from my understanding, there are supposed to be infinite branches of $\tan x$ (which keeps on getting shrunk as we move towards $\pi/2$).
Then do I say set $B$ and set $C$ have infinite terms, but then can I say both of them will have same number of terms?

You should show what you have tried so far. Are you allowed to use basic calculus knowledge?

I understand basic calculus and would be comfortable with it. Having said that it hasn't been covered in our syllabus yet. Would really be interested in a non calculus approach (if any)

I have tried to graph each function and check. But for cos(cosx) I'd be facing an issue as it has an inflection point

You should indicate in your question more details about your wor and effort.

It suffices you indicate at least what you have explained here in the comments.

I have tried to explain my attempt sir

Very nice! You should always explain your work and effort, and it was a good work.

For $B$ and $C$, once you establish that you have invinitely many solution they are "equals" in some sense. The both are countable as $\mathbb N$.

For the first one, more simply, we have that for $x\in(0,\pi/2)$ the identity $\sin(\sin x) = \cos(\cos x)$ requires
$$\cos x=\frac \pi 2-\sin x \iff \cos x+\sin x=\frac \pi 2$$
which is impossible, that is we have no solutions and elements in the set $A$.
For the others, you are right noting that $\tan x$ for $x\in(0,\pi/2)$ assumes all values $(0,\infty)$ and by a graph, since all functions are continuous in the interval, we can conclude that we have infinitely many (countable) solutions for $B$ and $C$.

[graph credits]

Regarding your final doubt, note that both $B$ and $C$ are countable sets since they can be made in one to one correspondence with the set of natural numbers.

Set $A$ is an empty set, which has been explained. The range of $\tan(x)$ is $\mathbb R$, so the number of the elements at the intersection of $\tan(\tan(x)$ and $\sin(\sin(x)$ and $\cos(\cos(x)$ is countable infinitesimus, that is, the number of elements in set $B$ and set $C$ is countable infinitesimus.

The fact that set $A$ is empty is not completely trivial to be proved you should show how we can conclude in this way. Do you mean "countable infinite"?

A is an empty set that has been illustrated by the another person. And sorry, my English is not very good.
